# Php mysql match (multiple) words in multiple columns with spaces

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how and what function i need for my query, still not sure on using Like, concat or what part etc.

My situation is as such

1.) I have multiple columns(Country, City, State, Location) 
2.) Only 1 search input 
3.) Search input can be 1 word, or multiple words also ignore spacing(e.g. "Center City or CenterCity or Center City Philadelphia) etc

And it will return the rows that matches the words from the different columns.

Below is my attempt, but it is not returning anything at the moment. Thanks for your time

Php:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

include 'connect.php';

if($_POST) 
{
$searchaddress = ($_POST['searchaddress']);



 $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
FROM Listing WHERE CONCAT(country,state,city,Location) LIKE '%$searchaddress%' AND Status='Open'") or die( mysqli_error($con));


        $output = array();

// fetch your results
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    // add result row to your output's next index
    $output[] = $row;
}

// echo the json encoded object
echo json_encode( $output ); 




        }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your exact data and what `$searchaddress` is like, it is hard to tell why it fails.

You are talking about ingoring whitespaces, but just pass in a single searchtag - and the expression `LIKE '%something something else%'` will not ignore whitespaces.

If you want to have the least amount of results with all given words matching, you should put in more effort and use a `or/and` combination of searchtags / columns. You can do this programmatically.

Assuming, you have 2 keywords entered: `Center Detroid`, you basically want to generate the searchquery:

```
FROM Listing WHERE 
 ( 
   country LIKE '%Center%' OR
   state LIKE '%Center%' OR 
   city LIKE '%Center%' OR 
   Location LIKE '%Center%'
 ) 
 AND
 ( 
   country LIKE '%Detroid%' OR
   state LIKE '%Detroid%' OR 
   city LIKE '%Detroid%' OR 
   Location LIKE '%Detroid%'
 )
```

To achieve that, you need to know two things:

- The fieldnames you want to search in.
- The keywords.

Then, the following snippet will generate the where part as required:

```
$search = "Detroid City Center";
$keywords = explode (" ", $search);
$columns = array("country", "state", "city", "location");

$andParts = array();
foreach ($keywords AS $keyword){
  $orParts = array();
    foreach($columns AS $column){
      $orParts[] = $column . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($keyword) . "%'";
    }
    $andParts[]= "(" . implode($orParts, " OR ") . ")";
}
$and = implode ($andParts, " AND ");

echo $and;
```

The example given in the array would produce

```
(
  country LIKE '%Center%' OR 
  state LIKE '%Center%' OR 
  city LIKE '%Center%' OR 
  location LIKE '%Center%'
) 
AND 
(
   country LIKE '%City%' OR 
   state LIKE '%City%' OR 
   city LIKE '%City%' OR
   location LIKE '%City%'
 ) 
 AND 
 (
   country LIKE '%Detroid%' OR 
   state LIKE '%Detroid%' OR 
   city LIKE '%Detroid%' OR 
   location LIKE '%Detroid%'
 )
```

This will Match ANY row, where *Center*, *City* or *Detroid* is appearing AT LEAST ONCE in ONE of all (search-)fields per row.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for searching each word in the address fields:

```
$searchaddress = "some address to find";
$address_parts = explode(" ", trim($searchaddress));
$sql_parts = array();
foreach($address_parts as $part) {
    $sql_parts[] = 'full_address LIKE "%'.$part.'%"';
}
$query = 'SELECT *, CONCAT(country,state,city,Location) AS full_address FROM Listing WHERE `Status` = "Open" HAVING '.implode(' OR ', $sql_parts);
```

Comment: Status is not reserved accordingt to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Status is one of those words that are not truly keywords but have meaning in MySQL. For example 'SHOW STATUS'

Comment: I tried it, it is exactly the same. I dont think my search criteria is correct, but i am not sure how to change it. Because at the moment it is treating my search field as 1 word, but i need it to search through all the different words. I tried totally removed the Status="Open", it still doesn't work

Comment: You mean that search each word in the input through all the adresss columns?

Comment: Yer, go through each word in each column, so in the end only the rows that matches all the words will be returned, Like (Center City Philadelphia) will only return the results that match that Location and City.

Comment: I am not sure if i supposed to use Like and run through each column but it wouldn't go through each word. Or if i use Preg_match

Comment: Just tried it, i have an error mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result and i added or die( mysqli_error($con) Then the error disappears, but i have nothing returned. Even when i set a static search input "Center City". Which i checked it is in the database. Not sure why

Comment: Have you added $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) before looping?

Comment: Yer it returned results, but it is doing exact word match. I think i need to break each word up and then run the like,Or in the query.

Comment: My updated answer already breaks the serch text in words and for each words looks into all the address fields.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, i just tried it again, it doesn't return anything tho, i tried to hardset a search field that i know exist in the database just to test. But it doesnt return any result. No error either